# Query not running in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this select statement that I am running in SQL Server. But it's throwing an error:

```
select count(*) 
from
    (select zip from A
     minus
     select zip from B)
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near select

What is the issue here? I have also tried aliasing the subquery but same error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing called `minus` in SQL Server, you need to use `except`.

Note, `except` in SQL Server is equivalent to `minus` of Oracle

Following query will work.

```
select count(*) ct
from
    (
     select zip from A
     except
     select zip from B
   )t
```

Another issue with your code is that you need to give a alias name to the inner table you are creating.